# Should you use undergraduate or graduate

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

Consider the scenario when someone asks me about my academic background 
If I reply - I have done undergraduation from university x and post graduation from university y. Is that correct?
or
I have done graduation from university x...mainly I am confused between using the words graduation and undergraduation.

Comment: You were _an undergraduate_ while you were studying for your first degree (that is, a student who has not yet graduated). When you got the degree you _graduated_. When you started on further studies you became a _postgraduate student_. You would need to specify what your second degree is (a master's degree or a doctorate).

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can say this. You can try this:

> I completed my bachelor's degree from X, and my master's degree [or PhD] from Y.

You can replace "bachelor's" with "undergraduate" and "master's" with "postgraduate" in the above sentence and it would be fine.

Or this:

> I did my undergraduate studies at X, and my postgraduate studies at Y.

And not "I have done undergraduation from" ...

Comment: Thanks. But then what's the difference between saying `I did my undergraduation from x` and `I graduated from x` are they both correct ?